# How can I search timeviewer.tv purely without the need to click on search for TeamViewer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, android, iphone, software-update

When you search for timeviewer.tv website, Google will tell "Do you want to search TeamViewer?" I need to know if you can tell me how can I search for timeviewer.tv purely without the need to click on search for TeamViewer instead? How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here, instead of search just go instantly to [www.timeviewer.tv](https://timeviewer.tv) or type timeviewer tv on the search, that's will make it easier to reach the website.